# java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase illegally accessing " " class controller/testManagedBean

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying for validation inside a picklist, so that not more than 1 item can be added into picklist. But I am getting following error when i use validator method inside a pickList.Can any one suggest me what I am doing wrong?

```
   java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase illegally accessing " " class controller/testManagedBean$1 
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1355)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreAttachedState(UIComponentBase.java:1598)






public void onTransfer(TransferEvent event) {
        PickList picklist = (PickList) event.getComponent();
        picklist.addValidator(new Validator() {

            @Override
            public void validate(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2)
                    throws ValidatorException {
                System.out.println("test");                     
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception looks pretty straightforward: You're attempting to add the validator too late in the component's lifecycle. Also, though I can't speak authoritatively on this but I don't think it's possible for a validator instance to be anonymous. Every occurrence of a validator within JSF requires some kind of id i.e. it's likely a requirement that it's independently addressable as a bean or a top-level method. It's simply safer to either specify the validation as a `validator` either as

1. Method definition on the picklist

   ```
   <p:pickList id="pickList" validator="#{pickListBean.validateSelection}" value="#{pickListBean.cities}" var="city" itemLabel="#{city}" itemValue="#{city}" />
   ```

   And on your backing bean, as a top-level method:

   ```
   public void validateSelection(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2)
               throws ValidatorException {
           System.out.println("test");                     
       }
   }
   ```
2. Full-fledged standalone implementation of a Validator

   ```
   @FacesValidator("myValidator")
   MyValidator implements Validator{

   public void validate(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2)
               throws ValidatorException {
           System.out.println("test");                     
       }
     }
   }
   ```